# Estimating number of frames and fps in opencv

Tags: python, opencv, ffmpeg, video-processing

I have some .mp4 video, ffmpeg shows me this info:

```
  Duration: 00:00:07.02, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 18001 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuvj420p(pc, bt709/bt709/iec61966-2-1, progressive), 886x1920, 14299 kb/s, 22.54 fps, 60 tbr, 600 tbn, 1200 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      rotate          : 270
      creation_time   : 2021-04-30T13:56:51.000000Z
      handler_name    : Core Media Video
      encoder         : 'avc1'
    Side data:
      displaymatrix: rotation of 90.00 degrees
```

So as I understand it should be 7.02 sec * 22.54 fps ~ 158 frames

When I try to read it in opencv:

```
def print_info_cap_reading(video_filepath):
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(video_filepath)

    fps = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)
    n_frames = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))

    print('fps:', round(fps, 2))
    print('n_frames', n_frames)

    counter = 0
    while True:
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        if ret == False:
            break
        counter += 1

    print('counter:', counter)
```

It shows me

```
# fps: 22.54
# n_frames 199
# counter: 175
```

When I tried to convert it to separate frames via ffmpeg it produce 422 frames:

```
ffmpeg -i source1.mp4 tmp/img%03d.jpg
```

So I wonder:

1. Why fps is float value and not int value?
2. What is the right way to estimate fps and number of frames?
3. Why cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT in opencv and actually reading frames produce different number of frames?

**Update:**

`-ignore_editlist 1` not helped, ffmpeg still produce 422 frames:

```
 ffmpeg -i source1.mp4 tmp1/img%03d.jpg
 ffmpeg -i source1.mp4 -ignore_editlist 1 tmp2/img%03d.jpg
```

Here is some ffmpeg output:

```
Output #0, image2, to 'tmp1/img%03d.jpg':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: qt
    com.apple.quicktime.author: ReplayKitRecording
    encoder         : Lavf58.45.100
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p(pc), 1920x886, q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 60 fps, 60 tbn, 60 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.91.100 mjpeg
      creation_time   : 2021-04-30T13:56:51.000000Z
      handler_name    : Core Media Video
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/200000 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: N/A
      displaymatrix: rotation of -0.00 degrees
frame=  422 fps=224 q=24.8 Lsize=N/A time=00:00:07.03 bitrate=N/A dup=247 drop=0 speed=3.74x
video:13709kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
```

**Update:**

`mkdir tmp3 && ffmpeg -ignore_editlist 1 -i source1.mp4 tmp3/img%03d.jpg` produce even more frames - 529.

```
Output #0, image2, to 'tmp3/img%03d.jpg':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: qt
    com.apple.quicktime.author: ReplayKitRecording
    encoder         : Lavf58.45.100
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p(pc), 1920x886, q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 60 fps, 60 tbn, 60 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.91.100 mjpeg
      creation_time   : 2021-04-30T13:56:51.000000Z
      handler_name    : Core Media Video
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/200000 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: N/A
      displaymatrix: rotation of -0.00 degrees
frame=  529 fps=221 q=24.8 Lsize=N/A time=00:00:08.81 bitrate=N/A dup=330 drop=0 speed=3.68x
video:16178kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
```

Comment: MPEG videos are just a stream of frames.  There is no "master header" that indicates the number of frames in the entire file, so the decoder either has to scan the entire file (which takes time), or guess, based on an average bytes per frame.  The guesses are not always accurate.

Comment: I wonder if ffmpeg made an effort to convert to 60 fps.

Comment: "Why fps is float value and not int value?" -- there's only one variant of get and set in the C++ API, and `double` can cover all the needed types of properties.

Comment: MP4 can have an *edit list* which can affect the number of frames output by ffmpeg. Default is to not ignore the edit list. You can ignore the edit list with the `-ignore_editlist 1` input option. Also, if your input is VFR then do you want the average FPS?

Comment: `-ignore_editlist 1` is an input option, but you are using it as an output option so it is ignored. Use `ffmpeg -ignore_editlist 1 -i source1.mp4 tmp2/img%03d.jpg`